# SQL contains string

Tags: java, mysql

I want to compare the string stored in column1 with column2 (contains the unique id of string)

- Column1: Facebook - Google Chrome
- Column2: Facebook
- Column3:..........

`Facebook - Google Chrome` compare with all the data in column2, if `Facebook - Google Chrome` matches with **Facebook** then I need to store **Facebook** in different columns (column3).

I need a SQL query for this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

SELECT (CHARINDEX(column1, column2) > 0)
FROM Table1

But you really need to provide more details in your question.